# Gearman PHP Installation on Windows

Tags: php, windows, pear, pecl, gearman

I'm trying to install Gearman php on Windows. I've read about PECL, PEAR, but I don't know how to install correctly with any one. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial for installing gearman http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/

Comment: This link redirects to a spam page (more precisely, to a "domain parking" site).